# Bind a .Net object to Crystal Report not finding properties

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a class called `Letter` which has 2 public properties `Letter_Header` and `Letter_Details`. I have successfully bound a .Net Linq object to Crystal reports but when I bind this object the properties are not being detected. How do I bind both the `Letter_Header` and `Letter_Details` to the report?

```
public class Letter
{
    public Letter_Header _header;
    public List<Letter_Details> _details;

    public Letter()
    {
    }
}


public class Letter_Header
{
    public Int32 ProductID;
    public String ProductName;
    public String BrokerName;


}

public class Letter_Details
{
    public Int32 ID;
    public Int32 PolicyID;
    public Int32 PersonName;
    public Decimal Amount;
    public DateTime DateTime;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be long dead, however just for the sake of completeness, here is an answer:

As I encountered Crystal Reports in Visual Studio does not accept own classes just basic built-in ones, in addition it cannot handle any form of collections.